# How does SHOW TABLES work - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to write a function to show all tables in a database:

```
function showTables($host, $user, $pass, $db){
    mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass)or die( "Unable to connect");
    mysql_select_db($db) or die( "Unable to select database");
    $show_table_query = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES");
    $tables=mysql_fetch_assoc($show_table_query);
    return var_dump($tables);
    mysql_close();
}
```

When I change the query to `SELECT * FROM table` I get a result set with all my rows just as I would expect.. but as it is `SHOW TABLES` my function returns:

`array(1) { ["Tables_in_internal"]=> string(8) "activity" }`

How do I get the result set to show me a list of table names instead?

EDIT
I know everyone on stack overflow is a huge advocate of mysqli but they're not even working on PHP6 at the moment and even when they do It will still be months/years before most people upgrade. So please save your breath.

Comment: Just to clarify,  you want to get a list of tables in you database?

Comment: Have you tried *fetching all returned rows* instead of just *one*? I also don't know what `mysql` has to do with PHP6. It's deprecated *now*.

Comment: to clarify further - i want a list of table NAMES.

Comment: `while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($show_table_query)){
       $tables[] = $rows;
    }`

Comment: Why do people have such a quick thumb to downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function showTables($host, $user, $pass, $db){
   mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass)or die( "Unable to connect");
   mysql_select_db($db) or die( "Unable to select database");
   $show_table_query = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES");
   $tables=array();

   while($table = mysql_fetch_assoc($show_table_query)) {
       $tables[] = $table;
   }

   var_dump($tables);

   mysql_close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [first example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-tables.php), the alternative to mysql_list_tables:

```
$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html the FROM is optional. besides I tried that already.

Comment: he need all table name from query.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:-

```
while($table=mysql_fetch_object($show_table_query)) {
 var_dump($table);
}
```

Comment: that gave me `object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["Tables_in_internal"]=> string(8) "activity" }`

Comment: instead of var_dump() do print_r() and see what it print.